# TreeView doesn't vizualize tree from TreeStore

Tags: haskell, treeview, gtk2hs

When I run this program, the treeWiew widget showed with white background and nothing else. I think, it's a bug but I'm not sure. I do not want report a bug which is not a bug.

```
testTree :: Tree String
testTree =
    (Node "root" 
        [(Node "child" 
            [(Node "rose" []),
            (Node "cry" 
                [(Node "karma" [])])]),
        (Node "future" []),
        (Node "destiny" 
            [(Node "call" []),
            (Node "saw" [])]),
        (Node "reason" [])])

start :: IO ()
start =
    builderNew >>= (\builder ->
        builderAddFromFile builder "graphic.glade" >>
        builderGetObject builder castToWindow "mainWindow" >>= (\window ->
            widgetShowAll window >>
            windowMaximize window >>
            (window `on` deleteEvent) (liftIO (widgetDestroy window >> mainQuit >> return True))) >>
        builderGetObject builder castToTreeView "treeView" >>= (\tv -> 
            treeStoreNew [testTree] >>= (\ts ->
                treeViewSetModel tv ts)) >>
        return ())

gtkmain :: IO ()
gtkmain = 
    initGUI     >>  
    start >>
    mainGUI  

main = gtkmain
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `>>=` and `>>` instead of do notation?  It might make your code more readable, which can help track down problems in your code.

Comment: I love operators >>= and >>

Comment: Fair enough, I just don't see many people who do.

Comment: I think you may need to explicitly re-draw the treeView after setting the model, but I'm not very familiar with using the builder/glade API.

Comment: I tryed functions widgetShow and widgetQueueDraw (for redrawing the widget), both called after setting treeStore and nothing changed.

Comment: Your setup is not complete. You need to add TreeViewColumns, CellRenderers and so on. They determine what pieces of data must be displayed and how the must be shown in the TreeView.